# How to safely delete a data directory after I have dropped a table?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

So I had dropped a table in Cassandra V3, and then recreated the same table, so that I could drop a few unnecessary columns (I know I should have used the alter command, wasn't too smart then, I guess).

Anywho, I performed this action more than a week ago, and all these records have a TTL of 8 days,

```
AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.TimeWindowCompactionStrategy', 'compaction_window_size': '1', 'compaction_window_unit': 'DAYS', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
AND default_time_to_live = 691200
AND gc_grace_seconds = 86400
AND max_index_interval = 2048
AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
```

So essentially, all data in the data directory for the old table should have expired by now. But I see the directories are not empty, and still consume space (~900MB). But when I check the dates, the last time these directories were updated is 1 week ago. So technically they are safe to be deleted. But is there a better, safer way to delete or clear those directories, without messing up production data?

Answer (score 0):

when you dropped a table it's not controlled by Cassandra anymore, so any activity, such as expiration of old data is not performed for it.  When the `drop table` was issued, Cassandra should create a snapshot for a table, with name like `dropped-<timestamp>-<table-name>`.   You can remove this snapshot from **every node** either by hand (last resort), or better with command `nodetool clearsnapshot -t snapshot_name`